# C++ assign member object function to class member function

Tags: c++, function, class, oop, object

Is there a way to use an = type assignment instead of this syntax:

`void triggerAttack() { adsr.triggerAttack(); }`

I was hoping to do something like:

`void triggerAttack() = adsr.triggerAttack`

`std::function<void()> triggerAttack = adsr.triggerAttack`

`void(*triggerAttack)() = adsr.triggerAttack`

but nothing compiles!

example code:

```
class LinearADSR
{
public:
    void triggerAttack() { }    
};

class JerobeamBlubb : public gen
{
public:
    void triggerAttack() { adsr.triggerAttack(); }

protected:
    LinearADSR adsr;
};
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? 1) fails because the syntax is invalid 2) and 3) fail because you have member functions, not normal ones (and you use an instance to get them)

Comment: Just make it simple to inherit certain functions, so I don't have to rewrite every function from one class to another. I didn't use subclass because I only need a few functions. But I could be repeating this kind of thing a lot, not avoidable. All sorts of customization needed for every class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, a member function pointer differs from usual pointers, since it has to be used with an instance of its class.

So change your code to this:

```
class LinearADSR
{
public:
    void triggerAttack() { }    
};

class JerobeamBlubb
{
public:
    void (LinearADSR::*triggerAttack)();
protected:
    LinearADSR adsr;
};

int main()
{
   JerobeamBlubb a;
   a.triggerAttack = &LinearADSR::triggerAttack; 
}
```

---

About your failed attempts:

- `void triggerAttack() = adsr.triggerAttack; is invalid syntax`
- `std::function<void()> triggerAttack = adsr.triggerAttack` fails because `triggerAttack` is a member function, and not a usual function. You need an instance of its class as I explained before.
- `void(*triggerAttack)() = adsr.triggerAttack` fails for the same reason as above.

Comment: I think, you are missing a very important bit: how to use that function. From what I gathered (very first code snippet), OP wants to use it like that: `a.triggerAttack()`

Comment: This is true, you can't use it like that?

Comment: `std::function` works with member functions. The problem is that it requires the first parameter to be a pointer to the object the function is being called on. If you already know the object at the time of construction, use `std::bind`.